# whatwg-fetch why isn't credentials included while in preflight (OPTIONS)

Tags: javascript, rest, cors, fetch-api

I am trying whatwg-fetch (polyfill for Fetch API) and when doing a POST, preflight is executed. But since credentials isn't sent when OPTIONS is sent to the REST service I receive an "unauthorized" response.

```
return fetch('http://localhost:8080/activity', {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  body: JSON.stringify(activity),
  headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
});
```

Comment: If you control the server, you need to configure the server so that it doesn’t require authentication for `OPTIONS` requests (there’s no reason why the server should require authentication for them, as opposed to `GET` or `POST` requests). But if you don’t control the server, there’s no way for browsers to make any cross-origin requests to it properly that require a CORS preflight.

Comment: I'm sorry but why does fetch api send a OPTIONS request?

Answer (score 1):

Take my case as answer. I believe that it will help you:

```
export function doSearchRequest (filters) {
    let token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    return (fetch('/services/search/message', { 
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cache': 'no-cache',
                '_token' : token,
                'X-CSRF-Token' : token,
                'X-XSRF-TOKEN' : token
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(filters)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(json) {
            return json;
        })
    );    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is all information about your case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request also here https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch . Browser send preflight OPTIONS request because you use cross-domain request